# UIScrollView inside UIScrollView: Scrolling

Tags: ios, uiview, uiscrollview, scroll

**Setup**:
I have a full-screen, parent `UIScrollView` that has paging enabled.  Then I have a small, second `UIScrollView` inside of the first one, with also paging enabled.

**Problem**:
If I swipe the second `UIScrollView`, it scrolls fine untill it runs out of pages, then the parent UIScrollView takes over scrolls.  For example, if I am on the last page on the second UIScrollView, swipe to left, the parent `UIScrollView` begins to scroll to right.  I tried enabling exclusiveTouch, but no change.

**Question**:
Is there a way if I scroll the second `UIScrollView`, only that will scrolls and stops, the parent `UIScrollView` will never move from that original swipe?

Answer (score 1):

You can set scrollView.scrollEnabled = NO; when other scroll is moving. You can detect when scroll begin dragging and didScroll.

Comment: Most the time, the issue is, trying to scroll the smaller scroll, instead of that scrolling, the parent one would scroll altogether....

Answer (score 0):

You can get everything with basic scrolling with full screen view from this one

https://github.com/zvonicek/ImageSlideshow

Trust me it really work and also work at rotating device.